# Native Ui Component vs. Native Module

Tags: javascript, react-native

In `React-Native`, what are the differences between `Native Module` and `Native UI Component`?
I am not sure if I understand the difference properly. When to use what? What are the pros and cons of them? The documentation is not really helpful (for me at least).

Comment: A native module is one *that you or some other third party wrote* in native code, e.g. a C++ NLP module. A native UI Component is a UI component native to the platform e.g. TextView on android. In this context, 'native' means something subtly different in the different cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly, a native UI module is a native widget that you can use as a component in your react components. And a native module is, more than a widget, any code you in a native page that you can invoke from react side.

For example, you may design a banner on iOS and Android, and then wrap it as a native UI module to use as  in your react native JSX code.

```
<Banner />
```

An example to a native module is, imagine you need to get the device token in your react page for push notifications. Currently there isn't a direct way to get the device token. Therefore, you'll need to implement your own, and you can use a native module in JavaScript codes:

```
NativeModules.DeviceToken.getDeviceToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated is kind of broad, but in terms of just explaining the difference a native module is one that you or some other third party wrote in native code, e.g. a C++ NLP module. Whereas a native UI Component is a UI component native to the platform e.g. TextView on android. In this context, 'native' means something subtly different in the different cases: in the module case 'native' means 'your code/library runs directly on the underlying OS' and in the second it means 'provided to you by the underlying OS'.

React native wraps most of the native UI components for you (like TextView) but there a few exceptions which is why you might need to use one.

Sometimes you need things JavaScript just doesn't give you (e.g. threads) which is why you might write a module in C++ and expose it to your React app with the native module APIs.

So there isn't really a comparison between the two, they're entirely different things.